# sencha touch HTMLDivElement in on click function

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch

Help me to get the particular `div id` result from `HTMLDivElement`

```
 wplStore.load();
 var itemTpl = new Ext.XTemplate('<div class="wpllist">'+
                 '<div><div class="wpl_txt_line1">{patientInfo}&nbsp;</div> <div class="wpl_txt_line1_right" style="float:right"></div></div>'+
                 '<div style="clear:both"><div id="patientId" class="wpl_txt_line2_left">{patientId}</div> <div class="wpl_txt_line2_right">{checkInTime}</div></div>'+
                 '</div>');

this.wplPatList = new Ext.List({
            id: 'wPatList',
            store: wplStore,
            itemTpl: itemTpl,
            height: 370,            
            indexBar: false
        });
        this.wplPatList.on('itemtap', function (view, item, event) {
        alert(event.innerHTML  + 'event');
            controller.showPatHisPanel(item);
         });
```

In `.on` function I want to get the `patientId` for which list I click for. How to get this? Please help me.

In event is coming as object `HTMLDivElement`, `event.innerHTML` alert I am getting the result

```
<div class="x-list-item-body"><div class="wpllist"><div><div class="wpl_txt_line1">Dinesh (Male, 9)&nbsp;</div> <div class="wpl_txt_line1_right" style="float:right"> </div></div><div style="clear:both"><div id="patientId" class="wpl_txt_line2_left">PAT-3407</div> <div class="wpl_txt_line2_right">Wed Sep 14 2011 06:07:00 GMT+0530 (IST)</div></div></div></div>
```

From this how can I get that `PAT-3407`? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If your store is correctly setup, you only have to do:

```
this.wplPatList.on('itemtap', function (view, item, event) {

   var record = wplStore.getAt(item);
   controller.showPatHisPanel(record.data.patientId);

}):
```